# No option for VsixContent in Build Action property for extension.vsixmanifest

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix, entity-framework-designer

I'm trying to create an entity framework designer extension and following the example from [Entity Framework 4 in Action](http://www.manning.com/mostarda/).  The book provides an example that is very similar to [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigl/archive/2010/01/14/extensibility-example-adding-custom-namespaces-in-your-code.aspx).  Note the "Note" under step 6 where he says to set the Build Action to VsixContent.  Well I don't have VsixContent as an option.  Anybody have any thoughts as to why this may be?

Thanks

**Edit**: It's worth noting that the vsix file isn't being generated. 
**Edit**: I reinstalled VS2010 SP1 SDK and rebooted.  I now see the option.  However, the vsix file still isn't being generated.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if that documentation is just too far outdated.  I created a Vsix Project and now the vsix file is being generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most up-to-date information I've found on creating extensions for the entity framework designer is this blog post: [Entity Framework Starter Kit alternative](http://www.jsrsoft.co.uk/blog/post/Entity-Framework-Starter-Kit-alternative). Hope that helps.